# GDScript modularization

Tags: godot, gdscript

### Is it possible to modularize in GDScript?

What I have in mind is that I have a `player` class with variable input, of type `IInput`, like this:

```
Player.gd:

extends KinematicBody

var input = load("res://Scripts/Inputs/PlayerInput.gd").new()

func _physics_process(delta):
    if input.is_down("left_trigger"): speed = sprintSpeed
    else: speed = runSpeed
```

Where `"res://Scripts/Inputs/PlayerInput.gd"` would look like this

```
extends "res://Scripts/Inputs/IInput.gd"
class_name PlayerInput

var controlTranslatinos = {"left_stick_up" : "move_up",
    "left_stick_down" : "move_down",
    "left_stick_left" : "move_left",
    "left_stick_right" : "move_right",
    "right_stick_up" : "rotate_up",
    "right_stick_down" : "rotate_down",
    "right_stick_left" : "rotate_left",
    "right_stick_right" : "rotate_right",
    "x" : "attack",
    "left_trigger" : "defend",
    "a" : "jump",
    "right_trigger" : "sprint"}


func pressure(controlName):
    var translatedControl = controlTranslatinos[controlName]
    var preasure =  Input.get_action_strength(translatedControl)
    return preasure

func is_down(controlName):
    return Input.is_action_pressed(controlTranslatinos[controlName])
```

and where "res://Scripts/Inputs/IInput.gd" would look like this:

```
extends Node
class_name IInput

const controls = [ "move_up", "move_down", "move_left", "move_right", 
                "rotate_up", "rotate_down", "rotate_left", "rotate_right", 
                "attack", "defend", "jump", "sprint" ]

func pressure(controlName):
    return 0

func is_down(controlName):
    return false
```

Goal is to change actor's input to `AIInput` class and back to PlayerInput on demand. This would also be good for other stuff.

Is it possible to implement this in some other way?

### Error at `PlayerInput.gd`

There's an error at first line of `PlayerInput`, saying:
`Script not fully loaded (cyclic preload?): "res://Scripts/Inputs/IInput.gd"

I get what cyclic preload would mean, but I don't get how cyclic loading is happening at this instance. Can you explain how/why this is happening? How can I overcome it?

If this error wouldn't show up I think the modularization would work (the way I imagine it works).

Comment: This may be due to an [engine bug](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/21461). Try removing the `class_name PlayerInput` and `class_name IInput` declarations from their respective scripts.

Comment: I just restarted godot and the error was no more (facepalm)